# Error 404 when trying to run asp.net core app on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I have an application based on asp.net core 2.0. When I trying to run it as a project in Visual Studio 2017 everything works fine, but when I publish it and try to run it through command prompt or with IIS hosting - the program works and it even provide some logs, but site is not working and when I try to access it I get 404 error. What could be the problem?

**Here is the output which I get in the command prompt:**

E:\Projects\DotNet\PublishTEST>dotnet .\RSSAggr

Hosting environment: Production

Content root path: E:\Projects\DotNet\PublishTEST

Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            using (var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppDbContext>())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
}
```

**appsettins.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\RSSAggregator.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you add the output of the command prompt in your post. That way we might be able to better identify your problem. Additionally you could try to run the `dotnet run -v d` or `dotnet run -v diag` command, this will generate substantially more output and might help to indicate if something went wrong.

Comment: I found out, that if I run project (not a publish build) using command prompt - the site  works, but If I try to run a publish build (as I said in the post both with a command prompt and IIS local hosting) it doesn`t work.

Comment: Could you describe the exact steps you use in order to host the application on IIS? I presume you first use the command `dotnet publish` and that this command works correctly (i.e. generates the files that need to be placed on the server)?

Comment: Adding to @Fluous questions: are you hoping to run InProcess hosting of your dotnet application or OutProcess? Does the IIS user have access to the folder you're deploying at? How is your site configured on IIS?

Comment: I create a folder to contain the app's published folders and files. Then I deploy the application to this folder. In IIS Manager, I open the server's node in the connections panel and I add a new website. Then I provide a site name and set the physical path to the app's deployment folder and name of the node ("localhost").

Comment: I have not chosen this, so I think the hostung will be default (OutProcess). Yes I provide IIS Manager with a physicl path to the app`s deployment folder. Sorry, but I do not understand what do you mean in "IIS configuration".

Comment: could you share a detailed error message snapshot?